# Coda slider hack - Marker movement using jQuery animate and position methods

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, coda-slider

Using [Coda Slider](http://kevinbatdorf.github.com/codaslider/) I am trying to get the markers (CSS triangles) to move when a new tab is selected. Here is what I am aiming for: [Design](http://deeplogic.info/kashflow/design.png), Here is my work so far: [WIP](http://deeplogic.info/kashflow/).

At the moment the arrow is drawn at the bottom of the navigation pannel on the left but I need it to move to the middle of the x coordinate of a tab when selected. Any ideas?

I can move the arrows on the chrome console using:

```
var position = ($(".current").position().left)-($(".arrows").position().left);
$('.arrows')
.find('.arrow')
    .animate({left: '+=500'}, 2000)
.end()
.find('.arrow-border')
    .animate({left: '+=500'}, 2000)
.end();
```

But whenever I try to use position as a variable to translate it, Its stops working. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I make some changes in "coda-slider.css" and "jquery.coda-slider-3.0.min.js"

you can't change the style from the "coda-slider.css" because there is style in the JQuery file "jquery.coda-slider-3.0.min.js"

you can download the source of the [Coin Slider](http://www.4shared.com/zip/mQ5ixbu8/Slider.html)

Comment: Surely it is possible to use jQuery's position().left method to find the x coordinate of the 'current' class tab and translate the arrow to this coordinate. I would have thought that this would be better than using separate images

Comment: yes it will be better than separate images, but I make it with CSS without using JQuery position

Comment: Download the file again, it is changed

Comment: I found an answer too but thanks for the help: http://deeplogic.info/kashflow/ (View Source to see changes - the code above in the action method for changing tabs)